# how to pivot a short table with start and end date into a long table of dates

Tags: r

How can I pivot a table of events in which each line is an event and it has the start date and end date to a table with the event in several lines and each line has a date when the event lasted.

follow example below.

note: dates in format "dd/mm/yyyy"

| Event | Start date | End date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Event A | 01/04/2023 | 05/04/2023 |
| Event B | 08/05/2023 | 14/05/2023 |

for

| Event | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Event A | 01/04/2023 |
| Event A | 02/04/2023 |
| Event A | 03/04/2023 |
| Event A | 04/04/2023 |
| Event A | 05/04/2023 |
| Event B | 08/05/2023 |
| Event B | 09/05/2023 |
| Event B | 10/05/2023 |
| Event B | 11/05/2023 |
| Event B | 12/05/2023 |
| Event B | 13/05/2023 |
| Event B | 14/05/2023 |

pivot a table by dates